# Apache RewriteMap directive with White List of IPs and IP Ranges

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, whitelist, rewritemap

I am trying to use the RewriteMap directive in Apache to "white list" (allow only) a mix of certain ranges of IPs and with specific IPs.  What makes this tricky for me is that the whitelist will contain a mix of large ranges of IPs such as 131.132.* (or in CIDR notation it would be 131.132.0.0/16) plus specific IPs also in the same list. My understanding is that you cannot use CIDR notation in mod_rewrite because RewriteConds just do simple text-string/character comparisons (Is this correct?).  So far, this is what I have come up with for my RewriteMap directive, but not sure it will work. Do you think the following will work to whitelist ranges of IPs in 131.132.*.* (131.132.0.0/16) ... i.e. start range 131.132.0.0 to end range 131.132.255.255) and the range 121.122.123.* (i.e. start range 121.122.123.0 to end range 121.122.123.255) and the specific IP 111.112.113.114, and will block all other IPs?  Also, will the back references (%1, %2, %3, %4) in the last three RewriteCond lines (note the RewriteCond lines are "OR'ed") work properly referring back to the first RewriteCond line for all references?

```
RewriteMap ipslist txt:"/path/to/whitelist.txt"
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)$
RewriteCond ${ipslist:%1.%2.%3.%4|block} ^block$ [OR]
RewriteCond ${ipslist:%1.%2.%3.*|block} ^block$ [OR]
RewriteCond ${ipslist:%1.%2.*.*|block} ^block$
RewriteRule (.*) - [F]

####
#### in whitelist.txt file
####
111.112.113.114     allow
121.122.123.*       allow
131.132.*.*         allow
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can only test in a live production environment which gives me heart burn. Still scratching my head a bit. One of my main uncertainties for me is whether or not the RewriteCond conditions of %1.%2.%3.%4 , %1.%2.%3.* , and %1.%2.*.* will find the proper matching entries in the whitelist file. For example, if a request were to come in from IP 121.122.123.101, would it find the match on the 121.122.123.* entry in the whitelist file and allow that one through. Not sure about the '*'s in the last two RewriteCond directives.  I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Will the back references (%1, %2, %3, %4, etc.) in the last three RewriteCond lines (note the RewriteCond lines are "OR'ed") work properly referring back to the first RewriteCond line for all references?

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution with the directive `Require`, this has not be deeply tested but seems to work :

```
Require ip 10.20.30.40/27 111.112.113.114 131.132
```